# Why does self become nil once creating init for a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

`private var messages = [Message]()` is instantiated in the ConversationView Class

In this instance, I pass in the otherUser's email and the conversationID. I use this init once the user's chat is pressed to pass in their information in the ConversationsView.

```swift
class ConversationsView: MessagesViewController {
    init(with email: String, convo_id: String?) {
        self.otherUserEmail = email
        self.conversationID = convo_id
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        if let id = conversationID {
            listenForMessages(convo_id: id, shouldScrollToBottom: true)
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is, is that self becomes nil somewhere in the process of the init, where it initializes the ConversationView and passes the values to the messages screen. In this case since self is nil, self.messages is not being updated. Is there any way to solve this problem?

```swift
class ConversationsView: MessagesViewController {
   private func listenForMessages(convo_id: String, shouldScrollToBottom: Bool){
        // Referencing a property on self in a closures, causes a retain cycle. Declaring weak self, makes the refernce weak, causing it not be a retain cycle.
        DatabaseManager.shared.getAllMessagesForConversation(with: convo_id, completion: { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let messages):
                print("Messages received \(messages)")
                guard !messages.isEmpty else {return}
                
                self?.messages = messages
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.messagesCollectionView.reloadDataAndKeepOffset()
                    if shouldScrollToBottom {
                        self?.messagesCollectionView.scrollToLastItem()
                    }
                }
    
            case .failure(let error):
                print("failure: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Here is where I init the params into the ConversationView

```swift
class MessagesView: UIViewController {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let model = conversations[indexPath.row]
        
        let vc = ConversationsView(with: model.otherUserEmail, convo_id: model.id)
        completionFunc()
        
        vc.title = model.name
        let targetUser = connections[indexPath.row]
        
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] in
            self?.completion?(targetUser)
        })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `nit(with email: String, convo_id: String?)`, that's returning a `Message` instance? If yes, is the `ConversationView` still present? Where is it "kept"? Maybe "enclose" your part of code with `extension` or `class` or `struct ItsName {}`, that way, we know of which one it is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, updated.

Comment: Where is kept ConversationView instance?

Comment: This instance is in the MessageView Class

Comment: Local variable of instance variable? And that MessageView instance, does it still exist? Ie. If you parent-parent-parent (any parent level you want) is released, then, the subparent should be too…

Comment: Make `vc` a property var of your class `MessagesView`. The issue is that it's deallocated too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Self is nil because ConversationView has been initialized.

Make sure ConversationView is retained after you initialized it.

```
// I'm guessing this is in some view controller, so self is the view controller
self.conversationView = ConversationView(with: "email@email.com", convo_id: "X")
```